# Deserializing XML file without converting xml file

Tags: java, xml, serialization

The below xml was generated by a system which needs to be converted by Java application into an object of type Employee.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Employee xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <Designation>Executive</Designation>
 <Name>Praveen Kumar</Name>
 <Salary>90000</Salary>
<BankAccount>10111</BankAccount>
</Employee>
```

How do I deserialize the above XML using XmlDecoder's readObject method without converting the xml file as it was generated by another system?

Comment: What do you mean by "without converting the xml file"? Why do you have to use `XmlDecoder`? Is this *actually* the XML format? If so, it would be near-trivial just to hand-code the deserialization.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can handle your use case:

### Java Model

The following class will be used for this answer:

```
package forum26609152;

public class Employee {

    private String designation;
    private String name;
    private int salary;
    private String bankAccount;

    public String getDesignation() {
        return designation;
    }

    public void setDesignation(String designation) {
        this.designation = designation;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getSalary() {
        return salary;
    }

    public void setSalary(int salary) {
        this.salary = salary;
    }

    public String getBankAccount() {
        return bankAccount;
    }

    public void setBankAccount(String bankAccount) {
        this.bankAccount = bankAccount;
    }

}
```

### XMLEncoder/XMLDecoder

Below is the XML that the XMLEncoder/XMLDecoder are expecting to work with.  It is very different from the XML in your question.  XMLEncoder/XMLDecoder is not a good fit for your use case.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<java version="1.7.0_60" class="java.beans.XMLDecoder">
 <object class="forum26609152.Employee">
  <void property="bankAccount">
   <string>10111</string>
  </void>
  <void property="designation">
   <string>Executive</string>
  </void>
  <void property="name">
   <string>Praveen Kumar</string>
  </void>
  <void property="salary">
   <int>90000</int>
  </void>
 </object>
</java>
```

### JAXB

JAXB is a standard API for object-to-XML binding.  An implementation has been included in the JDK/JRE since Java SE 6, so you already have it.

**Employee**

The mappings between the Java and XML are configured via annotations.  Below are the annotations necessary to map the Java object to the XML from your question.

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlRootElement(name="Employee")
@XmlType(propOrder = {"designation", "name", "salary", "bankAccount"})
public class Employee {

    private String designation;
    private String name;
    private int salary;
    private String bankAccount;

    @XmlElement(name="Designation")
    public String getDesignation() {
        return designation;
    }

    public void setDesignation(String designation) {
        this.designation = designation;
    }

    @XmlElement(name="Name")
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @XmlElement(name="Salary")
    public int getSalary() {
        return salary;
    }

    public void setSalary(int salary) {
        this.salary = salary;
    }

    @XmlElement(name="BankAccount")
    public String getBankAccount() {
        return bankAccount;
    }

    public void setBankAccount(String bankAccount) {
        this.bankAccount = bankAccount;
    }

}
```

**Demo Code**

Below is the code you need to write to read the XML into object form, and then output it back to XML.

```
import javax.xml.bind.*;
import java.io.File;

public class JaxbDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Employee.class);

        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        File xml = new File("input.xml");
        Employee employee = (Employee) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xml);

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(employee, System.out);
    }

}
```

**input.xml/Output**

As you can see this is the XML from your question:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Employee>
    <Designation>Executive</Designation>
    <Name>Praveen Kumar</Name>
    <Salary>90000</Salary>
    <BankAccount>10111</BankAccount>
</Employee>
```